# Tag attributes define for IE5 application causing issue working in latest browsers

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have started working on a very old IE application that needs to migrate to support the latest browsers.
I found in the HTML, that almost all elements using

> tag

attribute in it.
for e.g.
`<input type="checkbox" name="chkVendorCode1" value="1" tag="chkCheckVendorDelete">`

and on the jquery side its handles like below

`var chkList = $('input[type="checkbox"][tag="chkCheckVendorDelete"][checked="true"]');`

strangely this piece of code works only below IE8 versions but for chrome or any other later browsers, it's not supporting this.

now the main issue is, that this particular tag has been used 1000 times in the code and can not replace easily. Is there any way by which I can handle the **tag** and support the application to the latest browsers? I tried to figure it out on google but didn't able to find a single example of it, where the tag is used inside any HTML element.
Any help or idea really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'd probably attempt to replace `tag` with `data-tag` either in the codebase itself or via script.

Comment: Just off the top of my head it seems to me you should be able to change `tag=` to `data-tag=` everywhere, and that would be a simple search and replace (could do it with sed, awk, perl — lots of things)

Comment: i don't see why the tag attrib should not be usable in modern browsers. it works fine in my testing, maybe take another crack at it before moving moutains.

Comment: I guess this can be a possible solution, I'll try this

Comment: @user1599011, there are some complexity, if I change it all places not sure what it can break, application is working very much fine on IE5 but if I run anyscript or do replace all, I am not sure how many places it will change and what all it can breaks,
I can only make changes in JS side, as its common for all HTMls and that I can easily monitor also

Comment: You should be using a checked selector, not an attribute https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Comment: @dandavis, I have tried multiple times, in chrome the chkList length is 0 while in IE8 or below version its having length 1-2 based on the checkbox selected,This is pretty old application and huge also, I think, if I use selector, it can work and also easily revert back without any harm, changing tag to data-tag is the last option I am looking for,

Comment: @vicky9988: yeah, listen to the other comments here. JQ IE<9 uses a custom selector engine (sizzle) that behaves differently than the wrapper querySelectorAll that jq uses with modern browsers. Those two engines have different checked attrib handling. The tag attrib on it's own works fine in chrome et al.

Comment: It's broken as-is, right? So attempting to fix can only improve it.

Comment: `$('input[type="checkbox"][tag="chkCheckVendorDelete"]:checked')` works. (FF v101).

Comment: @Andy trying it out